# Netbeans FTP problems on Windows

Tags: netbeans, ftp, netbeans-7

I have Netbeans installed on my Windows 8 computer and my Ubuntu 12.10 computer. On my Ubuntu computer FTP works perfectly fine, but on my Windows computer it only works some times.

Usually when I download files on the Windows machine, it downloads most of the files, then it fails at downloading the rest. When I upload a file it sometimes uploads, aka:

- Netbeans sits and loads then asks if I want to keep FTP open for the session.
- Netbeans saves the file then doesn't even upload it (might be different issue)

But on Ubuntu I don't have any of these issues. What would be causing this?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I haven't tried lately, but I haven't found any fix for it. If it is working now though, maybe it is just a network issue.